# Ionic remove back button and display Menu button

Tags: ionic-framework, frameworks

I am new to Ionic and i would like to remove the back button and only display the menu button on all my pages. Where can i do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to add attribute persistent="true" to ion-menu

Like that.

```
<ion-menu side="left" [content]="content" persistent="true"></ion-menu>
```

then menuToggle button will be available on all views. 
You can find more details here in the [docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/menu/Menu/#navigation-bar-behavior).

For hiding back button you can try this code:

```
<ion-header>
   <ion-navbar hideBackButton >
    <ion-title>PageTitle</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
 </ion-header>
```

> I tested in my project. It works fine.